# Object creation timestamp

Tags: r, object, timestamp

Is there a way to retrieve the time an object was created at?

Comment: There was a similar question on mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-November/145016.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not generally but you can do it for objects you create yourself via

```
R> df <- data.frame(a=sample(LETTERS[1:5],10,TRUE),b=runif(10))
R> attr(df, "createdAt") <- Sys.time()
R> df
   a         b
1  B 0.8437021
2  D 0.8683446
3  B 0.5194791
4  B 0.0480405
5  B 0.5604978
6  C 0.1938154
7  A 0.1451077
8  D 0.1785405
9  C 0.3937795
10 B 0.2874135
R> str(df)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B","C","D": 2 4 2 2 2 3 1 4 3 2
 $ b: num  0.844 0.868 0.519 0.048 0.56 ...
 - attr(*, "createdAt")= POSIXct, format: "2011-03-16 10:42:10.137434"
R>
```

and you can then write yourself some custom `print()` or `show()` functions that use the attribute.  Frank Harrell's [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) and its Design predecessor have done something like that for a long time.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Yes, all you need to do is rewrite the assignment code in R's C core to store a datestamp somewhere every time an object is changed. I tried this once, storing the data in an attribute much like other answers here, but it had the unfortunate side-effect of making identical objects different. x=1 and y=1 had different timestamps, so identical(x,y) was FALSE and that broke R's tests in magnificent ways. I gave up.

Comment: You can still do this locally (ie within a given environment), by just overriding `<-` in R.

Comment: Hmm, this seems interesting.  I wonder if it's possible to store the timestamp in a different object, rather than as an attribute for the object itself, e.g. in a hashtable (via my new friend `hash`).

Answer (score 4):

Further to Spacedman's answer, and my comment there, see this example:

```
x <- 1
print(x)
# [1] 1

`<-` = function(...) {
  eval.parent(replace(match.call(), c(1, 3), list(base::`<-`, structure(..2, ctime=Sys.time()))))
}

x <- 2
print(x)
# [1] 2
# attr(,"ctime")
# [1] "2011-03-17 11:33:55 EDT"
```

You probably wouldn't want to do this in `.GlobalEnv`, but it could be useful within a localized environment.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying something myself in this direction with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Charles' function is great, but it can create problems in global environment.

I suggest to create a new operator `%c%` to be used instead of `<-`:

```
`%c%` = function(...) {
  eval.parent(replace(match.call(), c(1, 3), list(base::`<-`, structure(..2, ctime=Sys.time()))))
}
## object 1 older than object 2?
`%c<%` = function(x1, x2) {
  if (any(names(attributes(x1))=="ctime") && any(names(attributes(x2))=="ctime")) {
    attr(x1, "ctime") < attr(x2, "ctime")
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
## object 1 newer than object 2?
`%c>%` = function(x1, x2) {
  if (any(names(attributes(x1))=="ctime") && any(names(attributes(x2))=="ctime")) {
    attr(x1, "ctime") > attr(x2, "ctime")
  } else {
    NA
  }
}
```

The other two functions can be used to compare the time stamps. (With these latter functions I can avoid time-consuming calculations unless some argument objects have changed.)

```
> xx %c% 1
> xx
[1] 1
attr(,"ctime")
[1] "2017-09-14 17:01:03 EEST"
> xx + 1
[1] 2
attr(,"ctime")
[1] "2017-09-14 17:01:03 EEST"
> class(xx)
[1] "numeric"
> yy %c% 2
> xx+yy
[1] 3
attr(,"ctime")
[1] "2017-09-14 17:01:03 EEST"
> yy
[1] 2
attr(,"ctime")
[1] "2017-09-14 17:04:27 EEST"
> xx %c<% yy
[1] TRUE
> xx %c>% yy
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of not altering the objects, but instead save the timestamps the same way as history is being saved? R saves your console history to a file `.Rhistory` in the folder you're working in (i.e. `getwd()`).

I let R save timestamps (in Unix format, amount of seconds since Epoch = Jan 1st 1970 0:00:00) to `.Rtimestamps`, but only when this is set as an option:

```
#' @export
#' @noRd
`<-` = function(...) {
  if (!is.null(getOption("recordTimestamps"))
      & interactive()
      & environmentName(parent.frame()) == "R_GlobalEnv") {
    # only save timestamp when set in options, in interactive mode and in global env.
    if (getOption("recordTimestamps")) {
      write(
        x = paste(
          as.character(match.call())[2],
          as.double(Sys.time()),
          sep = ","),
        file = ".Rtimestamps",
        append = TRUE)
    }
  }
  eval.parent(
    replace(
      match.call(),
      1,
      list(base::`<-`)))
}
```

Usage:

```
options(recordTimestamps = TRUE) # only first time of course
a <- 123
# wait 5 seconds and change it
a <- 456
```

Now you only need to get those dates, which you can do with some helper functions that print valid POSIXct classes:

```
#' @export
#' @noRd
ctime <- function(object) {
  target_object <- deparse(substitute(object))
  get_cmtime(target_object, 1)
}

#' @export
#' @noRd
mtime <- function(object) {
  target_object <- deparse(substitute(object))
  get_cmtime(target_object, 2)
}

get_cmtime <- function(target_object, mode) {
  if (!is.null(getOption("recordTimestamps")) & interactive()) {
    # only get dates when set in options and when in interactive mode
    if (getOption("recordTimestamps") & file.exists(".Rtimestamps")) {
      lines <- readLines(con <- file(".Rtimestamps"), warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
      close(con)
      target_lines <- lines[grepl(paste0("^(", target_object, "),"), lines)]
      if (length(target_lines) > 0) {
        if (mode == 1) {
          # get first value, second element
          timestamp <- unlist(strsplit(target_lines[1], ","))[2]
        } else if (mode == 2) {
          # get last value, second element
          timestamp <- unlist(strsplit(target_lines[length(target_lines)], ","))[2]
        }
        ## transform to date
        return(as.POSIXct(origin = "1970-01-01", x = as.double(timestamp)))
      } else {
        return(NA)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And now it works like this:

```
> a
[1] 456
> ctime(a)
[1] "2018-02-07 10:43:03 CET"
> mtime(a)
[1] "2018-02-07 10:43:08 CET"
```