# identify the last r object (list) to be created in the Global Environment (eg in an RStudio session)

Tags: r

In SAS I used to reference the last data set I'd created using *LAST*.  Is there an equivalent in r? I'm including R programs using source() and afterwards I want to run the same code on the last data set in several R programs.  The name of the last data set isn't always the same.
I can get the names of the data sets I've created using ls.str(mode = "list") but this doesn't give the time.
I can get the time a file was created using file.info() but this doesn't work for lists.

Currently I get around this problem by hardcoding the name of the last data set.

Comment: I don't think R tracks timestamps. The closest I know of is [`.Last.value`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Last.value.html), which is very short-lived.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327555/object-creation-timestamp